# Jenkins BlueOcean stuck at "Pipeline Creation Pending."

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean, jenkins-github-plugin

My pipeline creation is stuck at pending stage on Jenkins server.  Nothing shows up on dashboard even after an hour. Tried multiple times but no luck.

When I try from my local Jenkins, it easily creates the pipeline for the same Git repository.

[image: ean]

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by updating Git API and Blueocean plugins in Jenkins to the latest version.